# Is this a proper rendering for "$b$ is a power of 2" using TNT from Gödel, Escher, Bach

Tags: elementary-number-theory, logic, formal-systems

In the book "Gödel, Escher, Bach" by Hofstadter introduces the system of "[Typographical Number Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typographical_Number_Theory)". One of the exercises is to write 'b is a power of 2', I ended up coming up with the following $<(a \cdot c)=b \supset \exists a':(SS0 \cdot a')=a \land \exists c': (SS0 \cdot c')=c>$ My interpretation into English of the phrase is "$a$ and $c$ being factors of $b$ implies that both and $a$ and $c$ are even" which I believe only holds true for $b$ that are powers of 2. Is this a valid way of writing 'b is a power of 2' in the system, and if it is/isn't how can I be sure.

Comment: You are correct. Is there a small modification that could be made to fix such a whole or is my approach generally flawed?

Comment: You are right : it works. $\forall a \forall b (a \cdot c=b \supset \ldots)$ means that we cannot have $24$ because for it we have also $3 \times 8$ and the two are not even.

Comment: LOL, Thanks. How can I be certain that there does not exist some spooky counter example?

Comment: What if $a=1$ or $c=1$?

Comment: @AlexKruckman then neither $a'$ nor $c'$ would exist. TNT only deals with non-negative integers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your formula doesn't quite work as written, because every number has $1$ as a factor. For example, $8$ is a power of $2$, but we have $1\cdot 8 = 8$, and $1$ is not even.

But the basic idea is correct. You can express "$b$ is a power of $2$" by "every factor of $b$ except for $1$ is even". I would write this as follows: $$\forall a\,  ((\exists c\, a\cdot c = b) \rightarrow (a = S0 \lor \exists d\, (a = SS0\cdot d)))$$

I'm not sure my notation matches Hofstadter's (for example I strongly prefer $\rightarrow$ to $\supset$ as a symbol for implication), but I trust you can make the notational adjustments necessary to translate my formula into a formula of TNT.

---

In the comments, you write "How can I be certain that there does not exist some spooky counter example?". You can be certain by proving it!

Suppose $n$ is a natural number. We want to prove that $n$ is a power of $2$ if and only if every factor of $n$ is either even or equal to $1$.

If $n$ is a power of $2$, then by uniqueness of prime factorization, the only prime number dividing $n$ is $2$. If $n$ has an odd factor $m$ with $m\neq 1$, then $m$ has an odd prime factor $p$, which is also an odd prime factor of $n$, contradiction.

Conversely, if every factor of $n$ is either even or equal to $1$, then since $1$ is not prime and $2$ is the only even prime, the only prime number appearing in the prime factorization of $n$ is $2$, so $n$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: You are correct in that your notation does not match Hofstadter's, though the main difference besides $\rightarrow$ versus $\supset$ is the way parentheses are used and lack of colons. That is a good proof. The one that I thought of in the mean time is that if a number is not a power of 2 then dividing it by 2 some number of times (zero times in the case of odd numbers) will eventually result in an odd number other than 1 and therefore an odd factor other than one exists.

Comment: I'm starting to feel skeptical about whether or not your answer has a proper rendering in TNT, could you give me a very literal translation of what you mean by what you wrote into English so that I can better understand what is meant?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by your last comment. My formula means (in English) "For all $a$, if $a$ is a factor of $b$, then $a = 1$ or $a$ is a multiple of $2$". Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: No, but that helped clarify it for me a bit. I was thinking something more akin to "For all $a$ such that there exists a number $c$ such that $a$ times $c$ equals &b$..."

Comment: Can you provide such a more verbose translation?

Comment: Never mind, I think the proper rendering would be $\exists a: \exists c: (a \cdot c)=b \supset <a=S0 \lor \exists d: (SS0 \cdot d)=a>$.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to universally quantify the $a$ and $c$. And yes, then your formula works since then it implies that $b$ has no factors other than $2$

Comment: Why do $a$ and $c$ need quantifiers?

Comment: @AaronQuitta  It is because "$b$ is a power of $2$" does not make reference to $a$ and $c$ ... so you don't want a formula that leaves $a$ and $c$ as free variables.

Comment: Got it, thanks.